# Cannot make timeout work properly on apache.commons.mail

Tags: java, smtp, timeout, jakarta-mail, apache-commons

My program work fine most of the time. However, sometimes my SMTP servers seems to close the connection or something and the program seems to not timeout at all.

I setup the following parameters available on commons.mail:

> SocketConnectionTimeout
> SocketTimeout

But it is not working as expected.

When my program hangs stays on this section:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.4
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "MY_SMTP_RELAY_SHOWS_HERE", port 25, isSSL false
{ No further output here }
```

My send-email code section looks like this:

```
try {
    // Create the email message
    MultiPartEmail mpEmail = new MultiPartEmail();
    mpEmail.setDebug(true);
    mpEmail.setHostName(mail_relay_hostname);
    mpEmail.setSmtpPort(smtp_port);
    mpEmail.setSocketConnectionTimeout(socket_Connection_Timeout);
    mpEmail.setSocketTimeout(socket_Timeout);
    for (String toAddres : email.getTo()) {
        mpEmail.addTo(toAddres);
    }
    for (String ccAddres : email.getCc()) {
        mpEmail.addCc(ccAddres);
    }
    for (String bccAddres : email.getBcc()) {
        mpEmail.addBcc(bccAddres);
    }
    mpEmail.setFrom(email.getFrom());
    mpEmail.setSubject(email.getSubject());
    mpEmail.setMsg(email.getBody());
    if (email.hasAttachment()) {
        logger.info("Email has attachments.");
        int count = 1;
        for (File file : email.getAttachmentList()){
            // Create the attachment
            EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
            attachment.setPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
            attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
            attachment.setDescription("Attachment"+count++);
            attachment.setName(file.getName());

            // add the attachment
            mpEmail.attach(attachment);
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("Email has not attachments.");
    }
    // send the email
    mpEmail.send();
} catch (EmailException ee) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    ee.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any TIP is welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I setup the timeout values in 120,000 (according to commons.mail the value is in milliseconds), which I expect to be a 2 minutes timeout.

Comment: Did you check socket status while it appears hung (with netstat)? What would happen in your code if some other exception would be thrown?